# Altering time card to show a employee took a lunch when the employee did not take a lunch

Tags: work-time

My employer was altering my time card to show that I took a 30 minute lunch when I didn't to meet the company policy of mandatory 30 minute lunch. He would then add 30 minutes to the end of the day. Is this legal? 
I  was a delivery driver and had to make stops within a time limit so I could get back to the warehouse and reload for a second trip therefore I wasn't able to take a lunch ever day. Each trip was about 150 miles with 10 to 15 stops.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you have been coerced into skipping lunch, or are doing it voluntarily? Those are two quite different scenarios, requiring actions by different people.

Comment: legal questions require that you specify the location.

Comment: The edit helps, thanks. For a task such as driving, there may be a health and safety angle (which I know too little about to answer). There may also be an element of wishful thinking on the delivery schedule planners that you "ought" to be able to make the deliveries according to their calculations, which then forces unsafe practices (not taking a break) if you cannot. Are you free to delay the schedule for your own safety - i.e. are you able to voluntarily work the hours that they are logging, but choosing not to for some reason (such as wanting to complete a working day on time)?

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you're in the UK.

On that day you either worked 8 hours, which means 30 mins overtime, or 7:30 hours, which means you left 30 mins early.

It's a [legal requirement](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/rights-at-work/basic-rights-and-contracts/rest-breaks-at-work-overview/) you are provided with a 30' lunch in an 8 hour workday, and your employer put it in your contract that you have to take it - so, it was really *you* violating your contract. Your boss decided to cover for you.

---

**edit** I didn't realize you work as a driver. Yes, your manager is probably breaking the law. I didn't focus on that because this isn't Law.SE, but it's important because of obvious safety concerns.

Comment: Not taking the lunch break breaks the law? The link you shared only says the employee is *entitled* to the break, not that he/she is *required* to take it. Could you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @MaskedMan Poor phrasing on my part, I crossed it out. You are entitled to a lunch break _during the day_ if you work more than 6.5 hours (ie you can't leave 30' early and call it lunch). Many companies (OP's included) do put it in their contracts as well, so OP is contractually obligated to take a lunch break. My pedestrian understanding of the law says the OP violated his contract by not taking a lunch break, and his manager covered for him.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't nitpicking. Poor phrasing on my part as well, I meant to ask how not taking the lunch break violates the contract, but got distracted by the link and asked a completely different clarification. :(

Comment: I am in the US and my workplace has the same policy, so I wouldn't assume UK. Otherwise I agree with everything.

Comment: It is possible that not taking a break violates a contract. A lorry driver (truck driver) who didn't take a break when required would be breaking the law. I'm not sure if that would apply to a delivery driver.

Comment: @DJClayworth I didn't realize OP is a driver. In this case I wouldn't overlook his manager breaking the law (which he did, but I didn't focus on, since this isn't law.se) because not taking enough breaks is dangerous for others as well.

Answer (score 3):

“Is it legal” is a bad question here. Not mentioning the country is worse. And you are in a bad situation: If you are not taking a mandatory lunch break, your employer can give you the choice between following the rules and seeking employment elsewhere.

What your employer did means you get paid for the time you worked. Complaining will get you into trouble. Take your lunch break.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the employer might be regarding this as a "Compensatory Work Break" (good link in rath's answer) to cover for an employee not following company policy - even if this wasn't the employee's choice.

Dependent on whether not taking the break at lunch time was the employee's or the employer's idea - including trying to meet unrealistic schedules - this could be covering for the employee, or covering their own backs. Or possibly both.

It sounds legal (depending on jurisdiction) but not what the people who wrote the company policy would want.

[Edited 07/07 after further information added to question.]